# How do I add a checkbox anchor tab to a document?

Tags: docusignapi

I've tried to add a checkbox anchor tab using the following code but it ends up just being a regular text field:

```
            var inputTab = new Tab
            {
                Type = TabTypeCode.Custom,
                CustomTabType = CustomTabType.Checkbox,
                CustomTabRequired = false,
                CustomTabRequiredSpecified = true,
                AnchorTabItem =
                   new AnchorTab
                   {
                       AnchorTabString = "Input41-1",
                       IgnoreIfNotPresent = true,
                       IgnoreIfNotPresentSpecified = true
                   },
                TabLabel = "Label" + i,
                DocumentID = "1",
                RecipientID = recipientNum
            };

            this.tabList.Add(inputTab);
```

Comment: Are you using SOAP or REST DocuSign API, and in which language are you developing your code?

Comment: I'm using the SOAP DocuSign API and I'm using C# to send the document out.

Comment: So the same seems to be happening when I add a custom "radio" tab as well. It's not showing up as a proper radio button, it's showing up as a small, adjustable input field for some reason. I'm basically looking for a simple example of a custom tab which is preferably a checkbox but could also be a radio button. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I am not C# person so I have added SOAP Request in the answer, you can first try to achieve result thru XML, also try below code `var inputTab = new Tab
            {
                Type = TabTypeCode.Custom,
                CustomTabType = CustomTabType.Checkbox,
                AnchorTabItem =
                   new AnchorTab
                   {
                       AnchorTabString = "Input41-1"
                   },
                TabLabel = "Label" + i,
                RecipientID = recipientNum
            };

            this.tabList.Add(inputTab);`

Comment: Make sure that AnchorString "Input41-1" is present in the document and you dont need to pass DocumentId as AnchorString is searched in complete envelope instead of a document.

Comment: I figured it out. I was missing this:

CustomTabTypeSpecified = true,

Thanks Amit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have below SOAP API example and it works fine in creating CheckBox and Radio Buttons,

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <ns:CreateAndSendEnvelope>
             <ns:Envelope>
               <ns:AccountId>{accountId}</ns:AccountId>
                <ns:Documents>
                   <ns:Document>
                    <ns:ID>32093411</ns:ID>
                    <ns:Name>DocName</ns:Name>
                    <ns:PDFBytes>{pdfBytes}</ns:PDFBytes>
                    <ns:FileExtension>pdf</ns:FileExtension>
                </ns:Document>
                </ns:Documents>
                <ns:Recipients>
                   <ns:Recipient>
                      <ns:ID>45399085</ns:ID>
                      <ns:UserName>Test Radio Name</ns:UserName>
                      <ns:Email>test@gmail.com</ns:Email>
                      <ns:Type>Signer</ns:Type>
                      <ns:RoutingOrder>1</ns:RoutingOrder>
                   </ns:Recipient>
                </ns:Recipients>
                <ns:Tabs>
                <ns:Tab>
                    <ns:RecipientID>45399085</ns:RecipientID>
                    <ns:AnchorTabItem>
                        <ns:AnchorTabString>/TextHereClient/</ns:AnchorTabString>
                    </ns:AnchorTabItem>
                    <ns:Type>Custom</ns:Type>
                    <ns:TabLabel>Checkbox1</ns:TabLabel>
                    <ns:CustomTabType>Checkbox</ns:CustomTabType>
                </ns:Tab>
                <ns:Tab>
                    <ns:RecipientID>45399085</ns:RecipientID>
                    <ns:AnchorTabItem>
                        <ns:AnchorTabString>/SignHereAdvisor/</ns:AnchorTabString>
                    </ns:AnchorTabItem>
                    <ns:Type>Custom</ns:Type>
                    <ns:TabLabel>Checkbox2</ns:TabLabel>
                    <ns:CustomTabType>Checkbox</ns:CustomTabType>
                </ns:Tab>
                <ns:Tab>
                    <ns:RecipientID>45399085</ns:RecipientID>
                    <ns:AnchorTabItem>
                        <ns:AnchorTabString>Test Anchor</ns:AnchorTabString>
                    </ns:AnchorTabItem>
                    <ns:Type>Custom</ns:Type>
                    <ns:Name>Radio</ns:Name>
                    <ns:TabLabel>Radio Group1</ns:TabLabel>
                    <ns:CustomTabType>Radio</ns:CustomTabType>
                </ns:Tab>
                <ns:Tab>
                    <ns:RecipientID>45399085</ns:RecipientID>
                    <ns:AnchorTabItem>
                        <ns:AnchorTabString>/SignHereClient/</ns:AnchorTabString>
                    </ns:AnchorTabItem>
                    <ns:Type>Custom</ns:Type>
                    <ns:Name>Radio</ns:Name>
                    <ns:TabLabel>Radio Group1</ns:TabLabel>
                    <ns:CustomTabType>Radio</ns:CustomTabType>
                </ns:Tab>
            </ns:Tabs>
                <ns:Subject>Email Subject Radio</ns:Subject>
                <ns:EmailBlurb>Email Blurb Radio</ns:EmailBlurb>
             </ns:Envelope>
          </ns:CreateAndSendEnvelope>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: I figured out what I was missing after seeing your SOAP. Thanks Amit!

CustomTabTypeSpecified = true,

Comment: Sure. Sorry, I wasn't sure how to do it.